# how does Facebook do Deep Linking in say their Photo Gallery pages?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm looking for a jQuery Rails deep linking solution...

Facebook has a great system as it doesn't have the ugly #s in the URL. Anyone know what they use and / or have any recommendations?

Comment: This post will be of interest to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849758/what-is-this-technique-on-facebook

Answer (score 0):

Um... here's the address from the address bar after the second image of a gallery view:

http://www.facebook.com/SomeUser#!/photo.php?pid=someNum&fbid=anotherNum&op=1&o=global&view=global&subj=yetAnotherNum&id=andAnotherNum

Looks kind of hashy to me. You can't mod anything in `location.href` without triggering a new request unless it's part of an anchor following the `#` symbol.

Comment: You must not be using a modern browser.. Safari 5, Chrome, FF4, all don't have the HASH

Comment: Well, FF3.6.10, so yes, up to date. It seems in Chrome, the entire page reloads. It's speedy because it's mainly cached. Perhaps you are mistaking this for deep linking?