# How does facebook rewrite the source URL of a page in the browser address bar?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, webkit, fragment-identifier

Go to http://www.facebook.com/facebook?v=wall, then click on the info tab. The content will be loaded, and the address bar now becomes http://www.facebook.com/facebook?v=info but the webpage didn't reload.

At first I think it is Ajax, but my question is, how do you change the address bar without reloading? I know I can change anchor (#wall) using JS but querystring (?v=wall), how?

Comment: i see a lot of vote and favorite, but anyone have answer?

Comment: And there is also load indicator in browser tab.

Comment: @Snoob: Give it some time, come on. People vote up because they want to know the answer too...

Comment: Because i am very bad english, so i need someone helpme to rewrite (make it more clear )this question, thanks

Comment: Isnt it same as in StackOverflow tabs ??

Comment: A similar behavior can be seen in Flickr too. Open any photo in Flickr and you'll see the photo sets on the right hand. Click on the photo set name and the Address bar value will change with out the page reloading.

Comment: Edited a better English for you ... please tell me if there's a mistake I didn't see :)

Comment: @Sandeep: No, because Stack Overflow doesn't use Ajax to load page content.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It's using HTML5's new [`history.pushState()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/history.html#dom-history-pushstate) feature to allow the page to masquerade as being at a different URL to that from which it was originally fetched.

This seems only to be supported by WebKit at the moment, which is why the rest of us are seeing `?v=wall#!/facebook?v=info` instead of `?v=info`.

The feature allows dynamically-loaded pages to be properly bookmarked, exchanged etc between JS-supporting and non-JS-supporting user agents. Because if you as a JS user linked someone to `?v=wall#!/facebook?v=info` and their browser didn't support JS and XMLHttpRequest, the page wouldn't work for them. The `#!` is also used as a tip to search engines to download the non-AJAX version.

Answer (score 19):

@Snoob - I'd appreciate it if you accepted [@bobince's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849758/what-is-this-technology-facebook/3849875#3849875) instead, he's was on the right track about the specifics first here. Since I can't delete/remove this until it's unaccepted I'll update it to be as correct as possible.

---

*At the moment* it's a **WebKit** (Chrome, Safari, etc.) specific thing you're seeing (or rather, not seeing), as @[bobince](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18936/bobince) points out in *other* browsers you can see the *real* URL in the bar:

```
http://www.facebook.com/facebook?v=wall#!/facebook?v=info\
```

Where Chrome just shows:

```
http://www.facebook.com/facebook?v=info
```

It makes a bit of sense, [given this is how you make AJAX Content crawlable with the Google search engine](http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html), so their browser recognizes where the content comes from as well.

*Correction on the specifics:*  Webkit browsers are showing the shortened URL facebook wants using the HTML 5 history features [you can see the code here](http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/zF/r/4A0A_IDcjJ7.js) (take a look at the `HistoryManager`) in this case specifically they're using [`.replaceState()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/history.html#dom-history-replacestate) to replace the URL you went to with the direct one available.

***Note:*** This answer may not be valid later (the WebKit specific bit), as other browsers support HTML5 features more and more this may become outdated quickly.

Comment: Great find Nick. A side note is that it´s probably a WebKit specific thing as it works the same in Safari.

Comment: @anddoutoi - I don't have Safari to test :) I'll update to include this...and a note that this answer may be outdated quickly as others support HTML5 bits more and more.

Comment: Interestingly, looking at the new Twitter design in a Webkit browser does **not** follow the same pattern that we're seeing on Facebook, i.e. I'm still seeing `/#!` in Twitter URLs but not in Facebook URLs.

Comment: @chigley - In this case the *reason* it works in WebKit is it's `history` support of HTML5, @bobince has the right idea, though for *this* particular example it's using `.replaceState()` instead of `.pushState()` (though facebook uses it elsewhere).  Check out the `HistoryManager` object here: http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/zF/r/4A0A_IDcjJ7.js

Comment: The `#!` information is useful too though. I hadn't seen this being specified as a standard spider behaviour before, hopefully other engines will pick it up too.

Comment: @bobince - There are other search engines??

Answer (score 0):

For MooTools developers I recommend checking out cpojer's [mootools-history](http://github.com/cpojer/mootools-history) plugin which provides support for the native history API when available, with a fallback to hashes.

Answer (score -8):

I don't have Facebook so I can't check. But I'm 95% sure that it has to be a full page request, the location bar is unwritable because this would be a very useful feature to absure for phishing websites (instead of http://fakeonlinebank.com it rewrite to http://yourtrustybank). It's probably just so fast that your browser appears to only load that part?

But I'm curious to see if someone will correct me on this, because that would mean they have the answer you do want to hear ;)

Comment: Thanks, i tried using Firebug to change somethings one facebook, then i click info tab and what i made still "alive" -> It isn't fullpage request

Comment: Could they be using client-side storage to speed things up?

Comment: Which browser do you use, in my Firefox (Mac) this is the URL I end up with http://www.facebook.com/facebook?v=wall#!/facebook?v=info, definitely the history hash technique.