# AJAX unique URL

Tags: javascript, ajax, facebook, url

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does facebook rewrite the source URL of a page in the browser address bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849758/how-does-facebook-rewrite-the-source-url-of-a-page-in-the-browser-address-bar)

Maybe this is a silly question, and I apologize if it's a simple one, but I'm not sure if I'm getting the terminology correct so I haven't been able to find any results with google.

I'm looking to change/modify the current page's URL (or specifically it's GET variables) using AJAX. I didn't think this was at all possible but it appears to be done in Facebook.

For instance when I'm on my facebook profile the url is written:
http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=xxxxx&sk=wall

Then if I click on the info link below my profile picture it changes to:
http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=xxxxx&sk=info

And there is no page refresh (as far as I can see).

So what's the deal, how is this done?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849758/how-does-facebook-rewrite-the-source-url-of-a-page-in-the-browser-address-bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot change the URL without a refresh except to add a hashtag anchor. You can use the `location.replace` method:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_replace.asp

**Updated to reflect @Crescent Fresh's link**

Looks like there is another option with HTML 5's `history.pushState()` (currently only supported by Webkit):

[How does facebook rewrite the source URL of a page in the browser address bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849758/how-does-facebook-rewrite-the-source-url-of-a-page-in-the-browser-address-bar)

Comment: I don't think that this is what facebook does. Firstly there is no hash in the link as you can see and unless I'm just missing it, I really don't see any refresh. I'm about to go through the source and try to figure it out. But if anyone already knows the answer please post it.

Comment: Wrong; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849758/how-does-facebook-rewrite-the-source-url-of-a-page-in-the-browser-address-bar

Comment: I'd make Tomalak's response the answer but it's just a comment. Thanks you guys.

Answer (score 0):

The page URL query-string cannot be modified without a new request, but its "[fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)" (the part after the #) can, with javascript (thus Ajax).

You can even leverage that using ScriptManager's `EnableHistory` property.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnableHistory="true" onnavigate="ScriptManager1_Navigate" />
```

and

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Do something.
   // ...

   //Then "remember the state".
   ScriptManager1.AddHistoryPoint("SomeState", "SomeStateValue"); 
}

protected void ScriptManager1_Navigate(object sender, HistoryEventArgs e)
{
  //Get the state back.
  String statevalue = e.State["SomeState"];
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Wrong; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849758/how-does-facebook-rewrite-the-source-url-of-a-page-in-the-browser-address-bar

Comment: @tiangoinu: It's not syntax sugar at all; it's a core language feature. Anyway, your claim that it cannot be done is clear simply wrong.

Comment: @Tomalak You are right in all counts. I was just kidding about syntax sugar, sorry it came out bad. Here, take a beer.