# How NOT to redirect when using window.document.href

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, location

Hey. I do use jQuery to "replace" content of page with new informations, but i'Ve got a problem.

I DO NOT WANT TO USE HASH!

So for example, I've got this page:

```
http://mydomain.com/
```

user clicks to "Cool page"
and ajax sends request to:

```
http://mydomain.com/coolpage
```

and I want to change link (adress bar) to:

```
http://mydomain.com/coolpage
```

but when ajax request is sent, I can't change adress bar URL by JS. How could I do that, without HASH ?

Comment: You want to change it to the same value?

Comment: Why are you using Ajax for this? The desired effect you are describing sounds like standard web navigation, i.e., user clicks a link, browser requests and displays the page associated with that link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's only supported in some web browsers. It's a new technology in HTML5. You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: It really does work! but problem is, that when I open source code, after that change, I see soure code of that new page (so It's requesting it), but I would rather not to "download" that file again. How?   I do use this right now: <script>var stateObj = { foo: "bar"};history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "bar.html");</script>

Comment: I have never used the API myself so I don't really know. But I thought that it wouldn't request the new page, it would just change the address bar to the new url. I thought that if you wanted to request the new page you had to do an ajax call to that page aswell.

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with the new [HTML5 browser history api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history), specifically, the `pushState()` method.

This is only available in newer browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

It's so easy with jquery plugin (adress)
Just look here and try it!

http://phpcode.eu/ajaxtest/

(feel free to use my code)

Comment: link id not working dude, i will be glad you post a new one or fix the existing one, thanks.

Comment: @PawanChoudhary: it's alive now :) Isn't woring in IE though

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849758/how-does-facebook-rewrite-the-source-url-of-a-page-in-the-browser-address-bar

Answer (score 0):

You can use [history.js](https://github.com/gregwebs/history.js/) that use HTML5 history API if supported and use hash if not supported. Syntax is same as HTML5 (`pushState()`).

There is no way no avoid hash in older browser if you want to manipulate URL