# How facebook overwrite link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, facebook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does facebook rewrite the source URL of a page in the browser address bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849758/how-does-facebook-rewrite-the-source-url-of-a-page-in-the-browser-address-bar)

When I click on a photo in Facebook, it makes an AJAX request. Then, my browser changes its address bar from:

```
http://www.facebook.com/home.php
```

to:

```
 http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=251545528207986&set=a.139901389372401.20498.100000576210972&type=1&theater
```

How does this happen? The page is the same; the only thing that changes is the address bar. Facebook also does not use hash marks (#!) like Twitter does; so then how can Facebook do that from an AJAX request?